# Mysqldump not working after upgrading to MySQL v5.5, many fixes tried, nothing working

Tags: mysql

I recently upgraded to MySQL v5.5, and my old mysqldump script broke and now gives me the error, "mysqldump: ambiguous option '--all' (all-databases, allow-keywords)".

Here's my original mysqldump line:

> mysqldump -h localhost -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD -c --add-drop-table
>   --add-locks --all --quick --lock-tables DATABASE > mysql_backups/DB-DUMP-`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S`.sql

So after looking around, I was told you don't need the `--all option`, and to use --databases `DATABASE NAME`, however I can't use this option as it includes the "`USE (DATABASE NAME)`" line in the output file, which won't work for my setup as this file is a 'live' dump that gets imported into another database, with a different name.

The next recommendation was to just use:

> mysqldump -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASE >
>   mysql_backups/DB-DUMP-`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S`.sql

Unfortunately this doesn't actually give me any data, but instead just this:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.31, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: DATABASE
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.5.31-cll

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2013-06-11  2:55:52
```

And after looking into *this*, it seems that most people are having this problem because of permissions, but the user I'm trying to dump this db with has absolute full privileges.

I've been scouring Google for quite some time now, being brought back to numerous other posts on Stack Overflow and all over the web, but nothing that's actually helped. I'm getting pretty frustrated and I'm not sure what to even attempt next, so if anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I still have no idea what was wrong, but instead of just a single mysqldump line I ended up trying a variation of [this script](http://mossiso.com/code/mysql-table-dump), and now everything's working. I'm baffled as to what was wrong with the other methods, but at least I can get back to work now.